# How set multi-line EditText with inputtype="number"?

Tags: android

I try set multi line for edittext if `imputtype="number"`
as:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtJianNo"
            android:layout_width="480px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/txtjianno"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="number|textMultiLine"
            android:lines="2"               
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="#5FB234"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
```

But value of edittext doesn't new line if length of value > length of edittext.
How set multi-line EditText with inputtype="number"?

Comment: by default edit text are multi line. for android:inputType="number" will set u number format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with only one attribute i.e. `android:numeric="integer"`.

**But it is Deprecated but for your question this is the only solution.**

**Code**

```
 <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10"
      android:gravity="top"
      android:lines="10"
      android:numeric="integer" />
```

Comment: if set android:numeric="integer". Keyboard don't show button Done.

Comment: @num please add this  android:imeOptions="actionDone"

Comment: what's the latest solution to it??

Answer (score -1):

You can **`edittext.setSingleLine(false);`**

Comment: `setSingleLine` is `deprecated`.